# Does a software under one of the OSI-approved licenses allow anybody to use/run it for any purpose?

Tags: licensing, license, osi

OSI (Open Source Initiative) says that:

> Open source software is made by many people and distributed under an OSD-compliant license which grants all the rights to use, study, change, and share the software in modified and unmodified form.

However, I can't understand what the rights exactly are in this definition. So that, I wonder software under one of the OSI-approved licenses (they can be seen [here](https://opensource.org/licenses/category) and [here](https://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical)) allow anyone to use/run it for any purpose.

For example, can I prepare a course (which shows the software's symbols/logos/icons/screen video records, use of it or its functions) with software under one of the OSI-approved license and sell it on Udemy?

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Answer (score 5):

The very definition of "open source" as defined by the OSI is, that the software may be used by anyone for any purpose.

As such, if you only use open source software which uses one of the OSI-acknowledged FLOSS licenses (e,g. GPL, BSD, MIT, Apache), you are fine.

The main differences in the licenses lay in the terms and conditions which apply when you distribute it and especially distribute modified versions of the software, be that in binary or source code form.